# Ruby: backslash all non-alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a script where I need to take a user's password and then run a command line using it. I need to backslash all (could be more then one) non-alphanumeric characters in the password. I have tried several things at this point including the below but getting no where. This has to be easy, just missing it.

Tried these and several others:

`password = password.gsub(/(\W)/, '\\1')`

`password = password.gsub(/(\W)/, '\\\1')`

`password = password.gsub(/(\W)/, '\\\\1')`

Comment: \w also includes the underscore, so if you also want to escape that, you'll have to take care, since \W will not do that for you.

Comment: Maybe try another way of escaping? `password = password.inspect`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, add more backslahes? =)

```
password = password.gsub(/(\W)/, '\\\\\\1')
```

This seems to work, see http://ideone.com/n3C0b

Don't ask me why!

Comment: Wow. This actually worked. Anyone know why? Seems like a few more backslashes then should be needed, but works great.

Comment: `password.gsub!/(/(\W)/, '\\\\\\1')`

Comment: that's not the same, @kurumi - if you got `password` passed in as a parameter, for example.

Comment: And it works because you need 4 backslashes in the literal to represent 1 backslash in the replacement. 2 backslashes in the literal mean 1 backslash in the string data, so the literal '\\\\\\1' is the string \\\1. Now, as the replacement string is not a plain string but is interpreted (otherwise \1 wouldn't work), backslashes there also need to be escaped, so the first two in the string (not the literal) give a single backslash for the replacement and the \1 is replaced with the first capture group.

Answer (score 4):

While Jens's pile of toothpicks does have a certain perverse beauty to it I think you might be better off with the block version of `gsub`:

```
password = password.gsub(/(\W)/) { |c| '\\' + c }
```

Go with whatever works for you though.

Comment: `password.gsub!` is not the same as `password = password.gsub`, which is very important when dealing e.g. with function parameters. also, `.gsub(/\W/) { '\\' + $& }` is more concise (and even in your form, the parentheses in the pattern are redundant).

Comment: @etarion: Fair enough on `gsub!` versus `gsub`, I changed that. But, I think "clear" is a better criteria for code than "concise", hence the extra parentheses and `c`; "clear and concise" is best of course but "clear" comes first.

Comment: the parentheses don't make it any more clear, they are just noise.

Comment: @Alan No, c is always the whole match. `ruby1.9 -e 'p "asdf".gsub(/d(f)/) {|x| x}'` => `"asdf"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a FYI -

Ruby 1.9 has [`Regex.escape`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Regexp#escape-class_method) built-into core:

```
strings = [
  'foo|bar',
  '(foo|bar)',
  '(?:foo|bar)',
  "foo/bar\n",
  "foo\/bar\n",
  "foo\/bar\\n"
]
regex = strings.map { |s| Regexp.escape(s) }
puts regex
puts '-' * 40
```

And, like @Nakilon said in the comment, there's inspect:

```
strings.each do |r|
  puts r.inspect
end
# >> foo\|bar
# >> \(foo\|bar\)
# >> \(\?:foo\|bar\)
# >> foo/bar\n
# >> foo/bar\n
# >> foo/bar\\n
# >> ----------------------------------------
# >> "foo|bar"
# >> "(foo|bar)"
# >> "(?:foo|bar)"
# >> "foo/bar\n"
# >> "foo/bar\n"
# >> "foo/bar\\n"
```